# I want to fully grasp the concept of a 'position: relative' containing div

Tags: html, css, position

Please bear with me... and excuse my (probably) incorrect terminology:

In the following code I don't grasp why you set the containing (parent) div to 'position:relative' in order for the divs inside to be positioned in relation to the parent div (using 'position:absolute). I thought in order for this to happen the children divs would be set 'relative' to the parent. Am I to understand that essentially the parent div is saying to the other divs inside "hey, you can all be positioned 'relative' to me now!" I sort of expected it to work the other way around.

E.g. I expected the text would have been positioned "relative" to the containing div. Can someone explain why it works the way it does here? Thanks.

```
<div id="backgroundImage">
    <h2 class="titleBox">I AM A TITLE</h2>
    <p class="textBox">I am a description box</p>
</div>

#backgroundImage {
position: relative;
height: 225px;
width: 300px;
background-image: url (#);
}

.titleBox {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
left: 0;
}

.textBox {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 0;

}
```

Comment: But the text *is* positioned relative to the containing div, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah totally, I just thought therefore the text position would literally be set to relative, instead of the container being set to relative. I'm just trying to wrap my head around why the syntax works this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You position the child elements absolutely, i.e you are specifying x/y co-ordinates for them (using `left` and `top` properties).

By default these will be positioned absolutely to the document, but by setting a parent container as `position:relative`, they will be positioned relative to that div, in an absolute manner.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning#Relative_positioning) explains this very well, but I'll summarize.

> An element with position:relative is first laid out just like any static element ... shifted according to the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties

The `position: relative` box *can* be adjusted relative to its parent (even if its parent is static).

For [`position: absolute`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Containing_blocks),

> the containing block is the nearest positioned ancestor. By “positioned” I mean an element whose position property is set to `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`

That is, the `top`, `bottom`, etc. properties on a `position: absolute` element are relative to the nearest containing element of a `position` other than `static` (including `relative`).

That is to say that `position: absolute` elements can still be positioned relatively.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your element as position 'absolute' it will be out of the DOM.So you can set where ever you want unless or until your absoluted element parent or parents of parent... does not having any position relative.why we use position relative actually is if u want to style the the element irrespectively with other elements inside container, u can set position relative to the parent(means container). If #backgroundImage does not have position relative , your child elements will go initial position of your screen but if u want some where in the middle of ur page u have to  styled the "backgroundImage" element as position :relative .. then the child element wil fly inside your  "backgroundImage" container.